# Heatmap: Append new data rows

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

I'm trying to add new data rows on an existing heatmap instance with Highcharts.

For me there are two ways of adding new rows to the heatmap:

1. at the top
2. at the bottom

**1.:**

Due to the fact how the Highchart heatmap data structure is designed (cf. [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cheatmap%3E.data)), the different data points coming from my backend need to increment in their `point.y` property, because the points with the highest y axis values are place on the top and that is where we want to place it.

This method works quite well in my case, so my pseudo code looks like that when I fetch new data from the server for 2nd, 3rd … time:

```
fetchData(loadIndex)
        .success(function (newData) {
            var numberOfDataRows = newData.z.length;
            var newHighChartData = makeHighchartData(newData);

            var cats = [].concat(chart.yAxis[0].categories);

            newData.y.forEach(function (newCat) {
                cats.push(newCat); // Add new categories at the top the chart aka. end of the array
            });

            chart.update({
                chart: {
                    height: 600 + numberOfDataRows * loadIndex * 30 // Update chart height
                },
                yAxis: {
                    categories: cats
                }
            }, false);

            // Add new data points

            newHighChartData.forEach(function (point) {
                var pointObj = {
                    x: point[0],
                    y: numberOfDataRows * loadIndex + point[1], // add new entry at the top
                    value: point[2]
                };

                chart.series[0].addPoint(pointObj, false, false);
            });

            // Redraw the chart… finally…
            chart.redraw();

            // Increment load index
            loadIndex++;
        });
```

This is working, but I'm not sure whether that is the best way of appending new data to the heatmap.

**2.:**

It is getting a bit more complicated imho when we want to add new data rows to the end (aka to the bottom) of the chart.

Then as far as I found out we need to update the existing data's `y` properties because they have to be shifted to the top and thus we need to assign larger property values.

I got it nearly working by using Highcharts `chart.series[0].setData(newData, false, true, true)` where I update the existing data with the `newData` (cf. last parameter `updatePoints` which I set to true) and the updated `y` properties. My version is kinda working, [except for the second reload it omits/hides the initally loaded data and I don't know why yet](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6201).

**But anyways… I'm asking myself whether that is the intended way of thinking and doing it? Do I miss something? Some helper method?**

Can somebody help me with that whether my ideas are correct and maybe someone can point me to some valueable example where data is appended to a heatmap. I haven't really found one, also not on the Highcharts documentation site which is great in general.

Comment: Your first approach is perfectly fine. For the second problem, please create a live example of it (jsfiddle/plunkr/etc.). If I have to manipulate the data from a chart I use a copy of data in the chart and manipulate original data without using Highcharts. Then I set new data with series.setData() method.

Comment: @morganfree Thx for your comment. I updated my post with a link to the highchart github issue I created. I did it exactly the same way using the `setData` method, but it has some weird behaviour I don't understand. Maybe it is a bug, maybe it is the implementation itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your first approach is fine, in the second you use Highcharts internal objects which you should not.

The problem is that methods like `setData()`, `addPoint()`, etc. expect pure js objects or arrays, but you use prototyped objects with a lot of additional properties - that leads to undesired behaviour.

You have initial data here:

```
var data = [
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 10],
   [2, 0, 8],
   [0, 1, 4],
   [1, 1, 6.5],
   [2, 1, 12]
];
```

Code for attaching new data for the bottom of the chart:

```
data = [
 // 1 row
 [0, 0, 5], // new data here
 [1, 0, 10],
 [2, 0, 15],
 //2 row
 [0, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 4],
 [2, 1, 10]
].concat(data.map(point => [
     point[0], point[1] + 2, point[2] //update old data
]));

   yAxis.setCategories(yAxis.categories.concat([
     categoriesLen + 1,
     categoriesLen + 2
   ]), false);

   chart.series[0].setData(data)
```

You need pure arrays and objects for updating the chart.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/44p52cha/

Comment: Thx a lot @morganfree. The issue was indeed that I mixed up the old data directly from the chart itself and not the pure array. Thx a lot!

Comment: I encountered another issue, after fixing the stuff you mentioned it "seems" to work as you can check out in my new codepen I did it (hopefully) in the correct way, see http://codepen.io/andi1984/pen/ygNyay. But when you insert new rows several times you can see that labels which are appended to the end, also appear at the top (e.g. label 44 is appearing me at the top and bottom) and I don't really know why. In my "real data" version it is completely killing the chart after five insertions (in total 120 rows) and it seems that the data values appear as labels. Do you have an idea on that?

Comment: It is the number of cells the chart has. When we append rows, the chart is broken when 1000 cells are added in total (you can also check it in your fiddle when you append many rows that you have more than 333 of them the chart gets completely black). Weirdly this issue does not appear when I prepend the rows. So there is definitely some issue there I guess.

Comment: @andi1984 See turboThreshold option http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold You add points as a three dimensional array, so the problem will occur if the number of points exceeds default turboThreshold value (1000). Disable it, by setting its to 0.